# New-IseSnippet in Powershell_ISE does not save variables?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I found the great snippet function in Powershell_ISE a days ago.
Unfortunately, the variables are not included when creating the snippet.
In the example you can see that $Somepath is missing.
I am currently making do by creating an empty snippet and manually copying the code into the XML.

I'm wondering why I don't read about this problem in any blog.
An example blog:
https://www.pdq.com/blog/creating-powershell-ise-snippets/

Example:

```
$title= "Just some Test"
$description="Just Some Test"
$author="Author xyz"
$text = @"
If (test-path $somepath) 
{

# If Path valid

} 

Else 
{

# If Path not valid
}
"@


New-IseSnippet -Title $title -Author $author -Description $description -Text $text
```

Output in Powershell_ISE after selection by CTRL+J and selection of the snippet.
In the xml the entry is missing too, of course.

```
If (test-path ) 
{

# If Path valid

} 

Else 
{

# If Path not valid
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?
The variables inserted later in the XML work without errors.

PSersion: 5.1.19041.868

Comment: Replace `@"` and `"@` with `@'` and `'@` (single-quoted here-string instead of double-quoted prevents varaible expansion)

Comment: Argh... that was easy.
How embarrassing..

Thank you very much!